# Why is there a difference between the height/weight in the Pokédex and Storage?

Tags: pokemon-go

After the latest update for Android, I was finally able to load the Pokédex and see what it had to offer. When viewing a Pokémon, it lists the height/weight as if you were viewing the Pokémon in your storage. I've only found one Aerodactyl, so I would figure the information would match; to my surprise they didn't match.

Pokédex Viewing:

- Height: 1.8m
- Weight: 59.0kg

Pokémon Viewing:

- Height: 2m
- Weight: 69.57kg

I've noticed this for multiple different Pokémon. Does anybody know have an idea why the numbers wouldn't match up?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure if it's a proportionally aligned with the IV and Max CP. Some speculation says that an XL height/weight means better pokemon, while XS height/weight means less capacity of that pokemon.

Comment: Since the Pokedex is an 'informational' section, perhaps it's merely displaying the average weight/height for each type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Appraisal text that is displayed when you have an exceptionally large or small Pokémon, it appears that the Pokédex entry is a height/weight reference, giving the average height/weight of that species.

[Here](http://pokemongohub.net/pokemon-go-appraisal-chart/) is a chart with all of the Appraisal quotes.

Note: These are quotes from Blanche, the leader of Team Mystic:

> Phase #3: Pokémon Size Size
>
> - Your [Pokémon Name] is tinier than any we have on record. Astounding.   **XS**
> - Your [Pokémon Name] is below average in size.   **Small**
> - Your [Pokémon Name] is above average in size.   **Large**
> - The size of your [Pokémon Name] is… colossal. This is indeed exceptional. Fascinating!  **XL**

Since height/weight have no bearing on a Pokémon's IVs or CP, these don't really mean anything for your Pokémon other than just being a fun fact.

Answer (score -1):

Just to make things a bit realistic by adding different Height, weight for each pokemon just to make them different as per the pokemon series which show some of the pokemon where strong and healthy and some are weak, so it can be considered as each pokemon can have different weight and height.
While pokedex keeping a fixed height and weight details for a pokemon.

Comment: Except their actual height and weight have no bearing whatsoever on their stats.